# How to check if date is yesterday

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am trying to find the difference between yesterday and today. If yesterday then execute. This is my code:

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date_posted), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.datetime.today()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
difference = abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:/Users/fatima.arshad/PycharmProjects/arabam/DailyArabamSpider.py", line 44, in parse
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.datetime.today()), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: .722653
```

Comment: You don't need to convert `datetime.datetime.today()` since it already returns a `datatime.datetime` object. Simply do `d2 = datetime.datetime.today()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the difference in days no need to cast the date to string then back to a date.

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date_posted), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d2 = datetime.datetime.today()
difference = abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

If you want to strip the microseconds use `.replace()`

```
d = datetime.today()
print(d)  # 2020-04-23 18:09:34.039505
print(d.replace(microsecond=0))  # 2020-04-23 18:09:34
```

That being said, using `timedelta.days == 1` determines if the two dates are at least 24 hours apart. If you want to know if it happened yesterday (e.g. today's Thursday, and other date is the previous Wednesday or earlier), compare using their dates as user @Daweo has suggested. Included below for the sake of completion:

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date_posted), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
d2 = datetime.datetime.today().date()
difference = abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

Comment: I have to undo it because it is not working for all

Answer (score 0):

As you are operating in terms of days, you might convert your `d1` to `datetime.date` and then compare it with todays `datetime.date` i.e.:

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date_posted), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
d2 = datetime.date.today()
difference = abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

Comment: There are 0 days in between `23 April 2020 59:59:59` and `24 April 2020 00:00:00`, but 1 day in between `23 April 2020` and `24 April 2020`

Comment: @GrandPhuba: my solution assumes that all dates are correct, so there is never `59:59:59` in any day

Comment: date_posted2020-03-23 00:00:00-09:30
 d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(date_posted), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File 
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: -09:30

Comment: date_posted is a non english date parsed like this date_posted = dateparser.parse(date_posted)

Comment: @user13370788: your date_posted `2020-03-23 00:00:00-09:30` is not compliant with format you request `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`

Comment: @Daweo apologies, I meant 24:59:59

Comment: @Daweo when I don't mention it then it gives some other error.

Comment: @GrandPhuba `24:59:59` is still illegal. For `%H` as docs says https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes `%H` values are `00, 01, ..., 23`